# how to use FILENAME to set different files in awk

Tags: unix

i have two files lets say...
1) student records having information like id,name and city
2) student marks having id ,totalmarks,percentage

Student Records (file)

```
101 | nik | mumbai
102 | zeel | chennai
103 | gurav | delhi
```

Student Marks (file)

```
101 | 80 | 80
102 | 90 | 90
103 | 90 | 90
```

and i want to retrieve a information in the forms like student name with it's percentage

```
nik | 80
zeel | 90
gurav | 90
```

how to write this using awk command

Comment: zeel's mark should be 90. (in output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$3}' studentfile markfile
```

didn't test, but should work.

output would be like:

```
nik|80
zeel|90
....
```

**Edit**

```
 -F'|'                   #Field separator
 -v OFS="|"              #output field separator
 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} #NR is overall record line number, FNR is record line number from one Input File. see man page for detail. this part was processing the first input file, and save id and name in an array
 $1 in a{print a[$1],$3}'#now processing the 2nd input file, the marks. if id in the array, print the value of the array (name), and the mark percentage field ($3)
```

Comment: can you provide some information about it how it is function ..
what is the mean NR=FNR

Comment: in this code first NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} will whole execute or whole actions write in ' ' is execute one by one....what happend can u tell me

Comment: `NR==FNR..` will only work on first input file.read man page, understand the difference  between NR and FNR